# How to group by and aggregate in openTSDB like RDBMS?

Tags: opentsdb

I have data in below format stored in openTSDB:

`src_ip    dst_ip    protocol    value   timestamp
1.1.1.1   2.2.2.1   tcp         100     100000001
1.1.1.1   2.2.2.2   tcp         100     100000001
1.1.1.1   2.2.2.3   udp         100     100000002
1.1.1.4   2.2.2.4   icmp        100     100000003`

They all belong to same metric say metric01.

I want to get the result like:

`select sum(value) from metric01 group by src_ip`

Is there any way I can get the result from http api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now way for openTSDB to do it. Also if there is requirement like this, then openTSDB may be not your choice. openTSDB is time series db, also for kariosDB. I tried in openTSDB and kariosDB and found they both can not.

Because in openTSDB , the group by is one thing, the aggregate is another thing.
Not like RDBMS, the agg works on the group by. In openTSDB the agg works on the downsample

Answer (score 0):

Like OpenTSDB, [Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) is based on HBase/HDFS and at the same time it supports SQL queries. Your grouping query will work just fine: https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/sql/#grouping

ATSD Community Edition is free.

**EDIT20160619**: Updated documentation links. Also, ATSD supports GROUP BY  with HAVING clause to filter grouped results. In addition, ROW_NUMBER window function can be used to apply LIMIT to resultset partitions.

Disclosure: I work for Axibase

Comment: It is really exciting to know this.  I`m looking for a solution on time series database.  Thanks, I will go for a check on the  Axibase Time Series Database First.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a way. OpenTSDB provides a rest API, you can use that.
For that, you need following things.

1. IP of a machine, where OpenTSDB is running.
2. Port of Opentsdb, the default is 4242.
3. Start time
4. Aggregator i.e sum,avg e.t.c
5. Metric name.
6. Tags
   As you want to aggregate on the basis of "src_ip", you don't have to mention it. The sample is given below.
   Assuming that, you are running OpenTSDB at your local machine.

   http://127.0.0.1:4242/api/query?start=10d-ago&m=sum:metric01{dst_ip=*,protocol=*}

Comment: Hi Rahman, Thanks but I`m afraid this does not work. This API has two problems. 1. The value returned for each src_ip group is not one value. But a list of map in the format like {timestamp: value}. Although we can use downsample to aggregate the value for each group into one value. But 2. those values can not be sorted. You have to sort by your own.